# React, how to update a state without repainting, or how to trigger useEffect without useState (and with useRef), or how to stop infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

### The situation

- I want to redistribute a grid based on the height of the images (using a masonry approach)
- Those images are lazy loaded

### What I want

- When the images are loaded, they send a flag, this flag makes the masonry logic to redistribute the grid, and everybody is happy
- Then when the user scrolls, more images are loaded, trigger the flag again and masonry again adjusts the grid

### What happens

* `const [myState, setMyState] = use State(0)`

- When the images are loaded I `setMyState(1)`
- In masonry logic, I have a `useLayoutEffect(() =>{}, [myState])` so when the state changes, I adjust the grid
- Then I reset the state with `setMyState(0)`, so that when a new image is loaded it will trigger again the `useLayoutEffect`
- **BUT**, when I reset the state it repaints the images, so the images get loaded again and trigger again the `useLayoutEffect`, which again resets the state, creating an infinite loop
- If I don't reset the state, the loop is stopped
- **BUT** then when a new image is loaded with the scroll, `setMyState(1)` doesn't change anything and the `useLayoutEffect` is not triggered

---

### So I'm now stuck

This is a simplified code

```js
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useState} from "react";

const wait = ms =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res("timed"), ms));

const Image = ({ setImageLoader }) => {
  // lazy load the image with an Observer, and then changes the state
  setImageLoader(1);
  return <></>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoader] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const update_grid = async stillMounted => {
      // change stuff
      await wait(10000); // careful with crashing chrome
      console.log("updated");
      setImageLoader(0);
    };

    const stillMounted = { value: true };
    update_grid(stillMounted);
    return () => (stillMounted.value = false);
  }, [imageLoaded]);

  return <Image setImageLoader={setImageLoader} />;
}
```

---

## Attempt 1

I cannot change the state in the `useLayoutEffect`, so I will change stuff only when the images are loaded and not again

## Problem

When I scroll and more images are loaded, I cannot triger the useLayoutEffect anymore

```js
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useState} from "react";

const wait = ms =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res("timed"), ms));

const Image = ({ setImageLoader }) => {
  setImageLoader(1);
  return <>hey</>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoader] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // change stuff
    const update_grid = async stillMounted => {
      await wait(40000);
      console.log("updated");
      // setImageLoader(0); NOW THIS IS NOT CAUSING THE REPAINT, BUT NEITHER WHEN NEW IMAGES ARE LOADED
    };

    const stillMounted = { value: true };
    update_grid(stillMounted);
    return () => (stillMounted.value = false);
  }, [imageLoaded]);

  return <Image setImageLoader={setImageLoader} />;
}
```

---

## Attempt 2

If I don't want the repaint, but want to trigger the useLayoutEffect, I could use `useRef` instead of `useState`

```js
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const wait = ms =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res("timed"), ms));

const Image = ({ imageLoaded }) => {
  imageLoaded.current++;
  return <>hey</>;
};

export default function App() {
  const imageLoaded = useRef(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // change stuff
    const update_grid = async stillMounted => {
      await wait(10000);
      console.log("updated " + imageLoaded.current);
      imageLoaded.current++;
    };

    const stillMounted = { value: true };
    update_grid(stillMounted);
    return () => (stillMounted.value = false);
  }, [imageLoaded.current]);

  return <Image imageLoaded={imageLoaded} />;
}
```

But codesandbox already warns me that `imageLoaded.current` will not cause a re-render of the component (even though I more or less wants this?)

So at the end, I see `imageLoaded.current` increasing when new images are loaded, but the `useLayoutEffect` is not triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to solve that using `useEffect` or similar

Instead, I've used a simple function to adjust the grid, and call it from the lazy-loading logic whenever it loads an image

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const wait = ms =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res("timed"), ms));

const Image = ({ adjustMasonry }) => {
  // lazy load the image with an Observer, and then changes the state
  const scroll = async () => {
    adjustMasonry();
    adjustMasonry(); // only causes one update due to the implemented buffer
    await wait(4000);
    adjustMasonry();
  };
  scroll();
  return <></>;
};

export default function App() {
  let signals = 0;
  const adjustMasonry = async stillMounted => {
    signals++;
    const last_signal = signals;
    await wait(200); // careful with crashing chrome
    if (signals !== last_signal) return; // as a way to minimize the number of consecutive calls
    if (stillMounted && !stillMounted.value) return;

    // change stuff
    console.log("updated");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const stillMounted = { value: true };
    adjustMasonry(stillMounted);

    return () => {
      stillMounted.value = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return <Image adjustMasonry={adjustMasonry} />;
}
```